# iOS Custom Animated Button does not scale back after pushing a page

Tags: ios, uibutton

My iOS Custom Animated Button does not scale back after a pushing a page. Is there a way to scale my button before its too late? Because when i return to origin page I see my button is still scaled small.

```
@interface CustomButton ()

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isSmall;

@end

@implementation CustomButton

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

    if (self = [super initWithCoder: decoder]) {
        self.isSmall = NO;
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]){
        self.isSmall = NO;
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (!self.isSmall){
        self.isSmall = YES;
        [self scaleToSmall];
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (self.isSmall){
        self.isSmall = NO;
        [self scaleToBig];
    }
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)scaleToSmall
{
    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    anim.duration = 0.100;
    anim.repeatCount = 1;
    anim.additive = YES;
    anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.8, 0.8, 1.0)];
    [self.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];

}

- (void)scaleToBig
{
    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    anim.duration = 0.100;
    anim.repeatCount = 1;
    anim.additive = YES;
    anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.25, 1.25, 1.0)];
    [self.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (self.isSmall){
        self.isSmall = NO;
        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
            [self.layer removeAllAnimations];
        }];
        [self scaleToBig];
        [CATransaction commit];
    }
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to scale it to big size whenever the view containing the button is about to appear.

Do that in the viewWillAppear: method of the view controller containing the button.

Comment: I am using these buttons all over the application. I suppose it would be very difficult to check all buttons and set the frame at every appearing.